# Table counting divisors

Tags: list-manipulation, column

I have a simple table that I can't quite make work. Columns are as follows

1. A function returning `1` if `x` divides `12` and `0` else
2. A function returning `1` if `x` divides `18` and `0` else
3. Columns `1` and `2` multiplied together to produce `1` if `x` divides both `12` and `18`, and `0` else
4. Column `3`s individual entries multiplied by the number of `1`s in column `3`, returning `4` if `x` divides both `12` and `18`, and `0` else
5. An accumulating sum of column `4`, which should therefore read `{4,8,12,12,12,16,16,16,16,16}`

I have problems with columns `4` and `5`. In the table below, I have had to manually enter the count for column `4` (`Count` just returns `0`), and the sum doesn't work in column `5` (the sum drops back to `0` whenever column `4` equals `0`, and I have no idea how it has managed to add together four `4`s to get `24`).

How do I fix this?

```
TableForm[
 Table[{If[MemberQ[Divisors[12], x], 1, 0], 
  If[MemberQ[Divisors[18], x], 1, 0], 
   If[MemberQ[Divisors[12], x], 1, 0]*
If[MemberQ[Divisors[18], x], 1, 0], 
   4*If[MemberQ[Divisors[12], x], 1, 0]*
If[MemberQ[Divisors[18], x], 1, 0], 
   Sum[
4*If[MemberQ[Divisors[12], x], 1, 0]*
 If[MemberQ[Divisors[18], x], 1, 0], {i, 1, x}]}, 
 {x, 1, 10}], 
TableHeadings -> {{"x=1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", 
"10"}, 
   {"D[12]", "D[18]", "D[12]D[18]", 
"(Count[D[12]D[18]])(D[12]D[18])", 
     "Sum[Count[D[12]D[18]])(D[12]D[18])]"}}, 
TableAlignments -> Center]
```

Comment: For #5, you've got `x` where you should have `i`, if you want to accumulate: E.g. `Sum[4*Boole[Divisible[12, i]]*Boole[Divisible[18, i]], {i, 1, x}]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps this, if I got the description of column 4 right:

```
With[{c1 = Boole[Divisible[12, Range@10]], 
      c2 = Boole[Divisible[18, Range@10]]},
     {c3 = c1*c2},
     {c4 = Total[c3] c3},
  Transpose@{c1, c2, c3, c4, Accumulate[c4]}
  ] // TableForm
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 0):

Similarly,

```
With[{t = Table[
    With[{result = Boole@Divisible[{12, 18}, i]},
     {i, Sequence @@ result, Sequence @@ ({1, 4} Times @@ result)}
    ],
    {i, 12}
  ]},
 Transpose@Join[Transpose@t, {Accumulate[t[[All, 5]]]}] // TableForm
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]